# Menu bar for each display

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, lxqt

Is there possibility to duplicate( clone ) menu bar on secondary display?
I user arandr to move my displays around and it works fine, but I also want to see menu bar on both of my screen, not only on the one I set as primary.

If it isn't clear from the tags, this question is related to Lubuntu, with LXQt.

Answer (score 5):

Yes...

You can have as many panels as you want, each can have it's own menu, quick launch bar (for app fast launchers) & more. It doesn't matter how many displays/monitor you have and you can have multiple panels on each... I do it (*I have panel at bottom, at side on one monitor, panel at top & other side on other monitor as it suits my setup which is atypical*).

Refer to the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html) for clues on using the Panel (*link I used is for the LTS or 20.04 release*).

To add another panel, move mouse over an existing panel and right-click (*in an unused area - this is the tricky bit; if you hover an item, the right-click will be interpreted as being for that item and not the panel itself*).

[image]

You'll get a new menu offering numerous items including

- Configure Panel
- Manage Widgets
- Add New Panel
- Remove Panel
- Lock This panel

(*Volume control options also appear in the menu I've pasted, as that's where my mouse was near*)

You click "Add New Panel".

A "*Configure Panel*" window opens, where you can use drop-downs to select which display, position on display etc, but once you've positioned it, decided if you'll reserve space for it, set colors/background, size etc, you can move to the Widgets tab and add the items you want there.

[image]

*Note: this picture is found on the manual; which is where I'll suggest you go. The only trick is the right-click is effected by whatever items you are hovering over, so try and pick an empty bit of the panel for the panel options to show; upper/lower edge can help*

https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html

Comment: My plan was to add a picture of the menu item I describe.. Picture taken, but it's full screen & I need to reduce it..   I'll add when I can...  (I'm not using *focal* so used a QA-test install of *focal* for picture which doesn't ....   I'll add if I can)

Comment: If the picture doesn't quite match how I describe my setup; it's because I grabbed the picture on a *focal* box; but was actually describing the preferred layout on my primary *impish* box (ie. *development* release).  Both boxes have multiple panels over multiple monitors, but the layout differs slightly on each as it suits my workflow better.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Install gnome extension Multi-monitor add on.

> https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/

Good Luck.

Update:

It is actually dash to dock as said in the other answer. I have both.

> https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Comment: How will this help?   Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop, so cannot make use of gnome-extensions... unless you firstly install GNOME & a load more...

Answer (score -1):

You can enable this feature using a widget called "Dash to Dock".

The steps I followed are:

- In Gnome Tweaks, go to Extension->Dash to Dock and select enable.
- Click the settings button.
- In the Dash to Dock dialogue box, select Position and Size
- At the top of this screen is the option to show the Dock on all monitors.

[image]

Comment: How will this help? Lubuntu uses the LXQt desktop, so cannot make use of gnome-extensions... unless you firstly install GNOME & a load more..

Comment: My answer was for Gnome on Ubuntu... now the question is phrased for Lubuntu, yes you are correct.

Comment: The original question tagged Lubuntu.   A later edit added LXQt, but that should have been implied by the Lubuntu tag (unless the OP added Lubuntu in error; GNOME wasn't ever mentioned).